# Get Distinct List of object with latest value

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of `product` objects

```
List<Product> products = new 
List<Product>() 
{
        new Product{ Name= "A", Code =1, TimeStamp= DateTime.Parse("26/06/2014 8:01") },
        new Product{ Name= "B", Code =2, TimeStamp= DateTime.Parse("26/06/2014 8:02") },
        new Product{ Name= "A", Code =1, TimeStamp= DateTime.Parse("26/06/2014 8:04") },
        new Product{ Name= "C", Code =5, TimeStamp= DateTime.Parse("26/06/2014 8:07") }
};
```

I want to get a distinct list of products with the latest Time value, so the expected output is -

```
Distinct Products
Name Code TimeStamp
A     1     8:04
B     2     8:02
C     5     8:07
```

I tried .GroupBy() but not working, any idea?

Comment: Please show your `GroupBy`, it's easier to fix that way.

Answer (score 13):

Using `GroupBy` is the right approach - order your groups, and take the first item, like this:

```
var res = products
    .GroupBy(p => p.Name)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(p => p. TimeStamp).First())
    .ToList();
```

The idea is to order each group by the timestamp in descending order, and then grab the first item from the sorted sub-list.

Comment: It's worth noting that if the groups were going to be *very large* then looking for the element with the maximal timestamp (e.g. via `Aggregate`) would be quicker than sorting and then taking the first. There's no suggestion that the groups here *are* going to be big, though.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use [MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) and `DistinctBy`:

```
var res = products
    .DistinctBy(p => p.Name)
    .OrderBy(p => p.TimeStamp)
    .ToList();
```